# Camera assets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need advice regarding the assets of the camera in unity.

I want to increase the level of my project and I think that some camera assets will do it well. They can be filters, effects, etc.

Any advises?

Comment: You should propably ask this question on Game Development SE. Besides, you should say more specifically, what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can browse assets on the [asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/)

Some of them are free, some of them aren't, but you'll always find something useful.

For a good start you can try  [Unity post procesing pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912) (quite good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0OQvWAPeuo) on this asset):

Comment: thx, i will check it.